# Spectre/Meltdown Patch Causing COM Method to Return E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, com, patch

I work on a project that uses COM heavily and the new Spectre/Meltdown patch has without a doubt messed with the communication within the program.

How Do I Know? I re-imaged a Windows Machine (May of 2017) where this patch didn't exist. I installed my program and everything works as expected. Then I downloaded all the required updates. The program no longer works. I then uninstalled the Meltdown/Spectre patch only (2018-01 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1507 for x64-based Systems (KB4056893)) and the program returns to normal behavior.

I hooked up the debugger to my program and traced it down to this section of code.

```
INvRtrControl4Itf * poRouterControl = GetNvRtrControl4();
if(poRouterControl)
{
    //the following line of code always returns E_ACCESSDENIED
    HRESULT hr = poRouterControl->GetXPTExtendedInfoForOutputs(lNumPorts, poOutputPorts, poXPTAndLPRInfo, peStatus);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        ConnectToRouterControl();
        poRouterControl->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    poRouterControl->Release();
}
```

Windows Debugger on an **Un-Patched** System :

```
poRouterControl->GetXPTExtendedInfoForOutputs returns S_OK
```

Windows Debugger on a **Patched** System :

```
poRouterControl->GetXPTExtendedInfoForOutputs returns E_ACCESSDENIED
```

I have a COM server A trying to communicate with a COM server B, both have the same permissions (SYSTEM). On the PATCHED system, when A invokes a method from the COM interface INvDevControl2Itf, the method is invoked by server B without errors. When that same server A tries to invoke a method from a different interface, INvRtrControl4Itf, on process B, E_ACCESSDENIED is returned and I never get across the COM interface. On an UN-PATCHED system, everything works as expected.

Has anyone encountered this problem yet with COM and the new Spectre/Meltdown patch? I will continue to look for the cause but the same exact code runs perfectly fine without the patch installed. However customers will want to update their systems eventually so I can't recommend and don't want to tell them to never install the patch.

Comment: I doubt the the Meltdown/Spectre changes would have broken all of COM, so it probably depends on what `INvRtrControl4Itf` is/points to/does. You'll have to step into that call.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe according to this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl the error message is a DCOM error... Perhaps the program is using DCOM and not COM... This program has been around for years and originally was meant for DCOM, however I was told that it has since been converted to COM... I'm doubting that idea now

Comment: All that `E_ACCESSDENIED` means is "Access Denied". It's not DCOM-specific. It might be a DCOM error; it might not be.

Comment: If the object was DCOM it might explain why the patch has broken this behavior since DCOM is deprecated and not used anymore @RogerLipscombe

Comment: I'm dealing with this same problem. No DCOM, just regular COM. I have a COM server in a windows service under the SYSTEM account, and a COM client in a user app without UAC elevation. I use `CoInitializeSecurity()` in both (`RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE`/`RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS` in the server, `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE`/`RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE` in the client). Been working fine for years. Install the KB patch and the client gets `E_ACCESSDENIED` from `CoCreateInstance()`. Remove the patch and the error goes away. Changing to `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL` like the KB says doesn't fix it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I changed the CoInitializeSecurity method initialization in only the caller COM service and everything is working like before, at least for the time being...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the [Windows Support Page on the Patch Itself](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056893/windows-10-update-kb4056893), I was able to resolve the issue of the COM service failing to call the method GetXPTExtendedInfoForOutputs by changing some code in my COM service's CoInitializeSecurity() method call

```
hRes = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE,
        NULL);
```

to

```
hRes = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, //<----------- changed
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE,
        NULL);
```

Although it solves the issue, it's somewhat troubling to know that some of the interfaces work perfectly fine with the original code where as others like INvRtrControl4Itf fail. Furthermore I didn't need to change the CoInitializeSecurity method initialization in the other COM service I am communicating with, only the caller COM service. The other COM service can still be intialized with RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE and my program works as before.

However, I did change all the CoInitializeSecurity method calls to use RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, this should mitigate the possibility of future E_ACCESSDENIED hresults. Unfortunately now that every call to the RPC server will require authentication, I am going to assume my program's performance may take a small hit. I doubt it will be anything of concern.

Perhaps this is why some people are noticing a performance hit when updating their systems with the Spectre/Meltdown patch... Just a thought.

Comment: There is no `RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_NONE`, did you mean `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE`? The KB says switching to `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL` is only needed if `CoInitializeSecurity()` fails with `STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`. If you switch the caller back to `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE`, do you then get that error? In my case, I only use `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL` if `STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` is reported, so maybe that is why the "fix" didn't work for me? Maybe I just need to stop checking for that error and use `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL` unconditionally? BTW, does `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT` work for you?

Comment: yeah you're right, not sure where i got RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_NONE from... Yeah I no longer check i just use RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL because it seems like Windows is recommending it and i figured it's better/safer to do that. I would recommend CoInitializeSecurity() with RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL wherever you were previously using RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE and hopefully that solves your issue. I have not yet tried RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT... @RemyLebeau

Comment: Using either `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT` or `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL` unconditionally now allows my client to connect to the server, thanks. But now the client is failing to advise an `IConnectionPoint` sink to receive events from the server.  Same `E_ACCESSDENIED` error

Comment: Windows is now requiring higher authentication between COM than before. Pre-patch our programs worked, post-patch our programs get E_ACCESSDENIED. Windows is now requiring higher security levels for certain interactions in COM. What happens if you use a higher authentication constant like RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY for both your server and client? Perhaps my program's interactions don't require higher authentication where as you are using a Windows defined interface and perhaps that interface requires a greater level of authentication because of the patch changes? @RemyLebeau

Comment: I'm using my own custom interfaces (the server is a central logging service I wrote for my company's software apps to send log messages to, and the service then sends events to a viewer app if it is running). I would prefer to keep using `_NONE` to allow the least resistance to apps using the logging service. `_CONNECT` and `_CALL` allowed the viewer to connect to the service when the patch is installed, but now the viewer can't advise its event sink with the server. Do you think using `CoSetProxyBlanket()` on the sink would work?